# Storing and retrieving unique token-level IDs in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We’re trying to index a large set of books (around 100.000.000 words) using Elasticsearch. Each word has previously been given an ID, here represented in HTML:

```
<span class="w" id="lb441882_1235">A</span> 
<span class="w" id="lb441882_1237">cold</span> 
<span class="w" id="lb441882_1239">morning</span>
```

We need to retrieve these IDs when searching the corpus. **What we have so far:**

1. We use a Delimited payload filter:

   ```
   {
       "type" : "delimited_payload_filter",
       "encoding" : "identity",
       "delimiter" : "|"
   }
   ```

   Storing the text as `token|ID`, e.g `A|lb441882_1235 cold|lb441882_1237 morning|lb441882_1239`
2. Getting the payload back inside of an `<em>` tag in the highlight search result, and manually splitting on |.

   ```
   'highlight': {'text': ['A|lb441882_1235 <em>cold|lb441882_1237</em> morning|lb441882_1239']}
   ```

This seems cumbersome because of the manual cleaning required but we haven't found a neater solution as of yet.

Questions:

Q1. Is there some better way to run a query against the payload text that gives the payload data in it's own field in the result? Ideally the hightlight would give offset indexes and the payload data rather than outputting html markup, **ideally** something that looks more like the data from `_termvectors`(in this made-up example):

```
{
    "highlight": [
        {
            "hit" : "cold",
            "position" : 1,
            "start_offset" : 2,
            "end_offset" : 6,
            "payload" : "lb441882_1237"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does any such thing exist?

Q2. Is the payload approach the best way to do this or should we be looking closer at custom analyzers? We've looked at the plugin linked from this article but couldn't get it to install:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-elastic-run-complex-search-using-annotated-tokens/29630/6

Comment: how are you indexing the words, do you use [HTML Strip](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html)? how does your words look before they go inside ES, e.g like cold|lb441882_1237?